# Automatically add ProductB once productA is manually added to Opportunity

Tags: trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, product

I was trying to accomplish this through a trigger, but its not really working. Is there a way to get this done through Process Builder? If so, what is that process?

I'm trying to have ProductB being added to the opportunity automatically once ProductA is manually added to the opportunity.

Also, is there a way to have the $ amount of ProductB being 0.5% of ProductA?

Trigger that I have so far:

```
trigger Attempt1 on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
for( OpportunityLineItem item: [SELECT  OpportunityId, 
                                        Name 
                                FROM    OpportunityLineItem
                                WHERE   Id = :Trigger.new AND 
                                        Name = 'NAME OF PRODUCTA'])
 {
  oliList.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
    OpportunityId = item.OpportunityId, 
    PricebookEntryId ='01uA000000QPDldEAt',
    Quantity = 1,
    UnitPrice = 25)
  );
 }
 Insert oliList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach, I have given comments in the code. Hope it helps.

```
trigger Attempt1 on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) 
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 

    List<String> lstProductNames = new List<String>();

    //create a list where all the products to be added.
    for(OpportunityLineItem optLineItem: Trigger.new)
    {
        if(optLineItem.Name == 'Product A')
        {
            lstProductNames.add(optLineItem.Name);
            lstProductNames.add('Product B');
        }
    }

    //retrieve the values based on Product list
    List<OpportunityLineItem> lstOpptyLineItems = [SELECT OpportunityId, Name , PricebookEntryId, Quantity, UnitPrice
                                                    FROM    OpportunityLineItem
                                                    WHERE   Id = :Trigger.new 
                                                    AND Name IN:lstProductNames];

    //create a map which contains Product Name and OpportunityLineItem
    Map<String, OpportunityLineItem> mapOpptyLineItem = new Map<String, OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem item:lstOpptyLineItems)
    {
        mapOpptyLineItem.put(item.Name, item);
    }


    for(OpportunityLineItem item: lstOpptyLineItems)
    {
        //retrieve the values and compare the name
        if(item.name == 'Product B')
        {
            //retrieve Product A item from the map.         
            OpportunityLineItem itemProductA = mapOpptyLineItem.get('Product A');

            //now assign Product A items as required, you can retrieve the amount from Product A
            oliList.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
                OpportunityId = itemProductA.OpportunityId, 
                PricebookEntryId = itemProductA.PricebookEntryId,
                Quantity = 1,
                UnitPrice = 25)
              );
        }
    }
    insert oliList;
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63854/discussion-between-hubby0716-and-santanu-boral).